# How to show modalwindow when user is leaving a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation in which i have to stop user from leave webpage, and when user click on X icon or moving away through page, i have to show a modal window with a offer (Image) once user click on image i have to open a special offer page having offer form.

How to achieve this -

1. To prevent from leaving the page?
2. How to generate a new random url for every click on modal window image, so no one can copy the offer page Url and forward to other users?

I have searched in google for preventing the user to go away and found the below code but i dont know how to use it properly. Any direction will be appreciated.

```
var warning = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
  if (warning) {
    return 'You have unsaved changes.';
  }
}
```

etc on this url: [JavaScript: Confirmation / Warning before Leaving or Navigating Away from a Page](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/04/javascript-confirmation-warning-before-leaving-or-navigating-away-from-a-page.html)

Please help me out, i am a new in php world.

Comment: That link you found is all you can do. Have that function return a non-empty string, and the browser will ask the user to confirm that they want to leave the page. You cannot control very much about how the browser asks the user.

Comment: @Pointy But how to show modal window with a image when user is leaving because i have to show offer image and user have to click on offer image so he/she will be redirected to special offer page. and every time new random url will generate for that offer page.

Comment: @Happy *it is not possible.* It would be terrible if it were.

Comment: see the site when you leaving the page a message will popup and a modal window will be popup too.

Answer (score 1):

You can only display a simple browser-generated dialogue (of the sort from the example you linked), anything more complicated is not possible.

Besides, unless you're trying to stop someone leaving a page without saving their work you're only going to upset and alienate your users.  You really shouldn't be trying for force a pattern of usage on your visitors.  They all have their own ways of browsing and if you try to force them into a different pattern they'll only resent it.